# Davenport's proof that almost all integers are the sum of 4 cubes

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, circle-method

Where can I find a pdf that describes Davenport's proof that almost all integers are the sum of $4$ cubes?

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02547752?LI=true

Comment: Almost all positive integers are the sum of three cubes and a minicube - see [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDsQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2F131.220.77.52%2Ffiles%2Fpreprints%2Fdiophantine%2Fbruedern%2Fwpminicubefinal.pdf&ei=Ud8bVJGaLsjWOfDrgIgE&usg=AFQjCNHab5VnqdniOWkQKE5qEn8ZBxUe2Q&bvm=bv.75774317,d.ZWU).